# Dart multiple installs on the system?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a bit of confusion about Dart and Pub installs on my system. I Use Android Studio and Flutter which comes with Dart, and if run `Dart --version` command in terminal I get `Dart SDK version: 2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "macos_x64"` which is the latest Flutter stable channel I installed.

Then to install Aqueduct with `pub global activate aqueduct` I was having the error pub command not found so I installed it and I had to also install PostgreSQL and Dart via home-brew .
Now to try and solve a bug that seems to be related to the latest version of dart [Aqueduct db generate error: Bad state: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608021/aqueduct-db-generate-error-bad-state-nosuchmethoderror-the-getter-length-wa)
I run `brew install dart@2.8` but then if I run `Dart --version` again I still get `Dart SDK version: 2.10.4 (stable) (Wed Nov 11 13:35:58 2020 +0100) on "macos_x64"`
Here is the print from console:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 7 formulae.

==> Installing dart@2.8 from dart-lang/dart
==> Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/rele
Already downloaded: /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f3ce4b575125184d766bb56931b479589b16972fb0bcfd1e00c841a316c85e25--dartsdk-macos-x64-release.zip
Warning: Your Xcode (11.5) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 12.3 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you an update run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

==> Caveats
Please note the path to the Dart SDK:
  /usr/local/opt/dart@2.8/libexec

dart@2.8 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have dart@2.8 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/dart@2.8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/dart@2.8/2.8.1: 502 files, 486MB, built in 34 seconds
```

How can I check what versions I have installed on the system and Flutter?
Many thanks

## Update

After running `brew uninstall dart` when I open the aqueduct project then I get `Dart SDK is not configured` message from Android Studio.
If I then point to the Flutter's dart-sdk folder Android Studio accept it but I need a 2.7 version to work well with Aqueduct's Postgres db.

So I guess the system should be set with both Flutter with its own Dart version for Flutter projects and a global Dart version for non Flutter projects like this Aqueduct project.
But then how do I set my path? Should I include both in my `.zshrc` file?

Comment: Maybe this section will help you: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path (see the note above platform setup)

Comment: See this answer and do likewise for dart: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783494/how-to-use-two-version-of-flutter-on-same-device-for-different-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out..
To have a different Dart version for non Flutter projects use Home-brew as install instructions say with `brew install dart` command and it will install the latest version.. If you need a specific version as I did install with `brew install dart@2.7`, and then to use it install docs says to use the `brew switch dart` command but I got  the `switch`  command is disabled in terminal message in terminal so I used the `link` command instead as suggested as `brew link --overwrite dart@2.7`
To set it in Android Studio the correct path is `/usr/local/Cellar/dart@2.7/2.7.0/libexec` as  when installing it the `dart@2.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because this is an alternate version of another formula.` message suggested it doesn't get installed in normal route `/usr/local/Cellar/dart` there you'll find the latest SDK installed with the first `brew install dart` command..

Update the path for it in `.zshrc` file and it's all done..

Hope this will help others as getting it set up correctly got me scratching my head a bit ..
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not to answer your whole question... addressing this part:

> I was having the error pub command not found so I installed it

`pub` is going away.  Learn to start typing "dart pub" or "flutter pub", depending on which subset of commands you want.

Comment: Hi Randal, Indeed when I still was trying Dart 2.8 in Android Studio Terminal window had to use `dart pub run aqueduct db upgrade` but `aqueduct db generate` worked just fine. Now on dart 2.7 I just use `aqueduct db generate` and `aqueduct db upgrade` commands. No `dart pub` or `flutter pub` needed.. do you know why is it so?